# What did I do wrong with this slide show code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I've coded a very simple slide show, that shows a new slide every 5 seconds. The slide show image names are: 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, etc. There is a total of 5 slides. When I refresh my browser, the slide show doesn't work. For the record, I coded this with the help of w3schools.com and other tutorials, and I literaly copied the code from the sites(of course I changed the variables). Even though I did that, it still doesn't work. Pls help.

JS code(in ):

```
<script type="javascript">
  var number=0;
  function change_slide() {
    number++;
    if(number>5) {
      number=1;
    }
    document.getElementById( "slider" ).style.backgroundImage="url(number + '.png')";    
    setInterval(change_slide, 5000);
  }
</script>
```

in body tag:

```
<body onload="change_slide()">
```

slide show div

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

slide show css

```
#slider {
  float:left;
  width:505px;
  height:330px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border:2px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Sorry for no code snippet, but the code of the site is to long.

PS.all slide show images all have dimentions of: 505x330 pixels.

Comment: The answer below will tell you why it doesn't work, however I'll add a side note and tell you that you should probably call `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. Calling `setInterval` will create a loop that happens, in this case, every 5000 ms. However, in this code you are creating that loop *every time* the function is called, which will quickly lead to this function being called dozens or hundreds of times every 5000 ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could consider changing your function to:

```
<script>
var number = 0;

function change_slide() {
    number = ++number % 5;
    document.getElementById("slider").style.backgroundImage = ["url('", number, "'.png')"].join("");
    setTimeout(change_slide, 5000);
}

</script>
```

This culprit line should be as pointed out by `@Matt L`.

Comment: So i changed the code to your code and still nothing. I even tried making a fresh div with no css, but also nothing;/

Comment: Ah! Ok, so i changed the "document.getElement" line to the one provided by @Matt L. and it works just fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: hi @AdamW. are you sure images are at those urls ?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is in this line here:

```
document.getElementById( "slider" ).style.backgroundImage="url(number + '.png')";
```

You put the var `number` inside of double quotes, which treats it as a string and not a variable. Change it to this:

```
document.getElementById( "slider" ).style.backgroundImage="url(" + number + ".png)";
```

Comment: So i used you code in @82Tuskers code and it works great! Thanks for the help!